# Eliminate the top-level field in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am using Logstash and one of my applications is sending me fields like:

```
[message][UrlVisited]
[message][TotalDuration]
[message][AccountsProcessed]
```

I'd like to be able to collapse these fields, removing the top level **message** altogether.  So the above fields will become:

```
[UrlVisited]
[TotalDuration]
[AccountsProcessed]
```

Is there a way to do this in Logstash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the names of all such subfields are known in advance you can use the [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html):

```
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => ["[message][UrlVisited]", "UrlVisited"]
  }
  mutate {
    rename => ["[message][TotalDuration]", "TotalDuration"]
  }
  mutate {
    rename => ["[message][AccountsProcessed]", "AccountsProcessed"]
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use a [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) (which works even if you don't know the field names):

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      event.get('message').each {|k, v|
        event.set(k, v)
      }
      event.remove('message')
    "
  }
}
```

This example works on Logstash 2.4 and later. For earlier versions use `event['message'].each ...` and `event[k] = v` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  I am trying to avoid this.  New data fields are going to be added fairly often and I'm trying to avoid mucking w/ the Logstash config each time that happens.

Comment: @MattW: So... wouldn't the ruby filter help then?

Comment: Oh wow, somehow I glossed right over the second part of the answer.  That works great.  Thanks for the help - I appreciate it!

Comment: We have to access event using get & set methods now, u should update the answer.