# Sending a field as the root field in Logstash

Tags: logstash

Working in logstash 5.4. Currently I have events that send all of their data in a "data" field and give a bunch of extra information I don't want in my elastic information at a root level. So a data structure that looks something like this

```
{
"index": "index-value",
"otherMetaData" : "stuff",
"data" {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
}
```

I want my logstash to just send the data part of this value so that elastic would get

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

And nothing else. Is there a set value as root plugin in logstash? Or an easy way to do this

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest is to set the source to "data"

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "data"
    }
}
```

you could also use filter mutate or a custom ruby script as explained by Magnus Bäck in [Eliminate the top-level field in Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28368575/2955337)

Elastic documented the [Event API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html) and [Field References Deep Dive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/field-references-deepdive.html). Those helped me  in understanding what `"%{[message]}"` means.